# Can I use a sound reinforcement (PA) amp with guitar cabinets?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I have separate power- and pre- amplifiers, and frankly, I am getting a little annoyed at my current poweramp.  My main complaint being that it is underpowered for my cabinet, and overpriced for replacement (it is starting to malfunction).

I also have a 350 watt (@ 8ohm) PA amplifier for monitors, that was cheap, and has worked reliably for 15 years.

As the poweramp for my guitar rig is solid-state, and does little to color the tone, is there any reason I cannot just use my Crown PA amp for my guitar rig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No reason. The power amps mainly boost the sound coming from the pre-amps. So they can be swapped. Why you need 350 watts for foldback is a question, unless you're playing 1,000+ venues or out in the open. Why haven't you just tried the idea?

Comment: I didn't want to melt my cab which does tend to get warm with a 100 watt power amp.  Also the power amp's current duties as a monitor amp powers the entire band's wedges, and competes with a demonstrably loud stage.  The house sound is usually only for vox.

Comment: Specifically, which cab gets warm - pre, post or spkr?

Comment: the speaker cab gets warm when run at 100 watts with my current power amp.  the power amp is running full tilt into it.  the cab's back plate says its rated for 300 watts at 8 ohms

Comment: @Tritium21: If the speaker cab gets hot, it sounds like something is wrong. I've never experienced this at least...

Comment: I am going to have someone look at my cab